# Service has leaked IntentReceiver in android

Tags: java, android

I am making an android app. I am making a service that runs in the background all the time when user checks a `checkbox` and it should stop when user `unckeck` it. So it does work when I check the box and it also shows "Service start" Toast but when I `uncheck` the `checkbox` then it shows the Toast that says "Service stopped" but it does not stop playing the sound which started when the service was started. The only way to stop that sound is to turn off my mobile and then turn it on.

Here is my java code for starting and stopping service

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    this.registerReceiver(this.batteryInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));

    return START_STICKY;
}
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Here is my xml file

```
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:title="Enable/Disable Alarm"
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:key="cbAlarm"
    android:summary="Enable or disable alarm" />
```

and here is my logcat

```
05-06 09:13:53.230: D/dalvikvm(5351): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 39K, 50% free  2725K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 124ms
05-06 09:13:53.355: D/dalvikvm(5351): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 21K, 49% free 2779K/5379K, external 504K/518K, paused 18ms
05-06 09:13:53.420: D/CLIPBOARD(5351): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
05-06 09:13:57.975: I/MediaPlayer(5351): uri is:content://media/internal/audio/media/44
05-06 09:13:57.975: I/MediaPlayer(5351): inside  getAudioFilePath: content://media/internal/audio/media/44
05-06 09:13:57.980: I/MediaPlayer(5351): The actual path is:/system/media/audio/ringtones/S_A_cricket_chirps.ogg
05-06 09:13:57.980: I/MediaPlayer(5351): path is: /system/media/audio/ringtones/S_A_cricket_chirps.ogg
05-06 09:13:57.980: I/MediaPlayer(5351): file path found for DRM file:path is: /system/media/audio/ringtones/S_A_cricket_chirps.ogg
05-06 09:13:57.980: E/MediaPlayer-JNI(5351): setDataSource: outside path in JNI is ?x@
05-06 09:14:20.525: E/ActivityThread(5351): Service com.zafar.test.BatteryService has leaked IntentReceiver com.zafar.test.BatteryService$1@40536548 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
05-06 09:14:20.525: E/ActivityThread(5351): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Service com.zafar.test.BatteryService has leaked IntentReceiver com.zafar.test.BatteryService$1@40536548 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
05-06 09:14:20.525: E/ActivityThread(5351):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:756)
05-06 09:14:20.525: E/ActivityThread(5351):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:551)
05-06 09:14:20.525: E/ActivityThread(5351):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:866)
05-06 09:14:20.525: E/ActivityThread(5351):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:853)
05-06 09:14:20.525: E/ActivityThread(5351):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:847)
05-06 09:14:20.525: E/ActivityThread(5351):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:318)
05-06 09:14:20.525: E/ActivityThread(5351):     at com.zafar.test.BatteryService.onStartCommand(BatteryService.java:35)
05-06 09:14:20.525: E/ActivityThread(5351):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2043)
05-06 09:14:20.525: E/ActivityThread(5351):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-06 09:14:20.525: E/ActivityThread(5351):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:998)
05-06 09:14:20.525: E/ActivityThread(5351):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-06 09:14:20.525: E/ActivityThread(5351):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-06 09:14:20.525: E/ActivityThread(5351):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
05-06 09:14:20.525: E/ActivityThread(5351):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-06 09:14:20.525: E/ActivityThread(5351):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-06 09:14:20.525: E/ActivityThread(5351):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
05-06 09:14:20.525: E/ActivityThread(5351):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
05-06 09:14:20.525: E/ActivityThread(5351):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-06 09:14:37.810: D/CLIPBOARD(5351): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
```

Help please. Where am I making mistake.

**Edit**

```
private BroadcastReceiver batteryInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
        int plugged = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, 0);

        if(plugged == 2) {

                SharedPreferences getAlarms = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
                String alarms = getAlarms.getString("ringtone", "default ringtone");
                //getting uri from MediaStore via filepath i.e. content://media/internal/audio/media/29
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(alarms);

                mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                try {
                    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, uri);
                    final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context
                            .getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                    if (audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM) != 0) {
                        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
                        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                        mMediaPlayer.start();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //System.out.println("OOPS");
                    e.getStackTrace();
                }
        } else if(plugged == 0) {
            mMediaPlayer.stop();
        }

    }
};
```

Comment: On my phone, played sounds will continue to play even after the application completely quit. Maybe it's just an Android thing. Have you tried stopping the sound from the service?

Comment: Hassan I didnt get your point "Have you tried stopping the sound from the service?" Could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: I mean, in the code that actually plays the sound, how do you pause/stop the sound? Do you pause/stop it?

Comment: Hassan see my update above thats where I start and stop sound

Comment: anyone who can solve my problem? Please

Comment: Sorry, I went to sleep before you I saw your message. allprog's answer is good, though!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure you call `unregisterReceiver`before the `onDestroy` finishes. After `onDestroy` the Service's context is invalid, so all registered intent receivers will stop operating. Android warns you with the "Leaked intent receiver" exception that your app is misbehaving.

The music does not stop because the receiver is not called any more. You should ensure that mMediaPlayer.stop is called before the return from onDestroy. I suggest you extracting all this functionality into separate methods, thus it will be much easier to compose your application.

```
private void startMusic(int level);
private void stopMusic();
```

Also, be careful not to leak the mMusicPlayer if due to error you receive two plugged == 2 intents in a row. It is always better to write your code in a defensive way, rather than relying on the invoker's additional knowledge.

The exception handling is also quite dangerous in your code. If the music starting failed, it may happen that you get a null pointer exception when you want to stop the music.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks allprog. This helps and you provided good info. Since I am new to android thats why my code is not like professionals. Could you tell me where and how in my code can I unregister my receiver?

Comment: I used this "this.unregisterReceiver(this.batteryInfoReceiver);" in onDestroy() method but it does not work.

Comment: I'd say this is the worst part of Android. The APIs you need to use here are very ambiguous and you need to understand the internal workings of Services and BroadcastReceivers to see how it should be done.
Have you tried putting the unregisterReceiver call before super.onDestroy()? What error do you get?

Comment: I'm working with an external device which is sending intents via Bluetooth. even when I unregister the receiver, I still get this exception. this is probably because it takes time for the data to reach after the receiver has been unregistered. Could be the same on your side.

Comment: @allprog I am getting the same error and i am calling the  unregister before calling super. Did you guys resolve this issue??

Comment: @free_style I think the OP got this solved. I suggest you post a new question as your issue may be caused by something else. Though, before going further, I suggest you make the intent receiver a `const` field to make sure it cannot be lost once initialized. Then check the sequence of events, probably by logging stuff in your methods and using the debugger.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you missed the @Override annotation

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(batteryInfoReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be a bit late but seems you have to call unregisterReceiver() right before the onDestroy() method is called. This solved my issue.